# How does ASP.NET routing work internally?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

OK I have seen many tutorials on how to use URL routing. However, I'd like to know how it is implemented internally by Microsoft.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the following links

[How ASP.NET MVC Routing Works and its Impact on the Performance of Static Requests](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2010/04/01/asp-net-4-0-enables-routing-of-extensionless-urls-without-impacting-static-requests.aspx)

Comment: For 1st link see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2010/04/01/asp-net-4-0-enables-routing-of-extensionless-urls-without-impacting-static-requests.aspx

Comment: @Santosh second link disappeared